# Access a specific element clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following method

```
PMm.test = function (){
  ....plenty of code....

  $('.element',this.page).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    console.log(self);
    this.load(someoptions)
  }.bind(this));

  ...plenty of code....

}

PMm.test.prototype.load = function(options){
  ...some code
}
```

When `console.log(self)`, it returns the method `PMm.test`. How do i access the element clicked if `$(this)` is the entire function scope where i declare my event ? Knowing that i also need to call the `.load()` method which is declared later on.

Comment: Why is your click event inside of the function? They are typically set globally. That alone might help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it'd be best to store the context in a variable an access it using closure in your callback. It'd lead to a more readable code.

```
PMm.test = function (){
  ....plenty of code....
  // Store the context in a variable.    
  var that = this;
  $('.element',this.page).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // this here references the DOM element (as expected)
    var self = $(this);
    console.log(self);
    // you can access your methods through that.
    that.load(someoptions)
  });

  ...plenty of code....

}

PMm.test.prototype.load = function(options){
  ...some code
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: indeed i needed to remove the .bind(this)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `this` for something else (because of the `bind`), you can use either:

- [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) - This is the element the event actually occurred on, which may be a descendant of the element that you attached the handler to.

  or
- [`e.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) - This is the element the handler is attached to. (What's normally `this` in jQuery callbacks if you don't use `bind`.)

E.g.:

```
PMm.test = function (){
  // ....plenty of code....

  $('.element',this.page).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var elementClicked = $(e.currentTarget); // or $(e.target);
    // ...use it...
    this.load(someoptions)
  }.bind(this));
```

Example:

```js
function ClickResponder(name, selector) {
  this.name = name;
  $(selector).on("click", this.handler.bind(this));
}
ClickResponder.prototype.handler = function(e) {
  console.log("this.name = " + this.name);
  console.log("e.target.tagName = " + e.target.tagName);
  console.log("e.currentTarget.tagName = " + e.currentTarget.tagName);
};
new ClickResponder("respond-o-matic", ".foo");
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="foo">
    <span>Click me</span>
  </div>
  <div class="foo">
    <span>Click me</span>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `[function].bind(this)` you are binding `this` (PMm.test) to the jquery event, overwriting `this` (element) set by jquery. 
If you need both inside the function you don't need to bind the object, instead, making the object PMm.test accesible using a variable:

```
PMm.test = function (){
  ....plenty of code....

  var obj=this; //obj references to PMm.test

  $('.element',this.page).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    console.log(self);
    obj.load(someoptions)
  }); //no .bind()

  ...plenty of code....

}

PMm.test.prototype.load = function(options){
  ...some code
}
```